# Snowflake wildcard

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I face what semms to be stupid problem. Here is a reprex:

```
CREATE TABLE demo_db.public.tsquery
 (id number,
  extid varchar
 );

INSERT INTO tsquery
  VALUES 
  (1, '202475dhsgWM–332'),
  (2, '102832dhsgGG–332'),
  (3, '182644sWMGFL–332')

SELECT * from tsquery;

---
ID  EXTID
1   202475dhsgWM–332
2   102832dhsgGG–332
3   182644sWMGFL–332
---
```

and that is OK. But when I run

SELECT * FROM tsquery WHERE extid LIKE '%WM-332';

the query returns nothing. Please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a Snowflake problem.

It seems that you inadvertently used the wrong dash symbol. The data uses `–` which is a long dash, while the query uses `-` which is a short dash. On my keyboard I don't even have a long dash !